# hydro pr2 gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro, ubuntu, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using ros-fuerte and ros-groovy before. I was using the PR2 robot. Now that I want to make the robot appear under ros-hydro but I'm having some troubles.

The first command I was using to load the gazebo environment

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

And now in hydro is:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

Gazebo is loading and working fine. Next is to load the robot, I was using:

```
 roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

I've looked for the pr2.launch file and now it's in */opt/ros/hydro/share/pr2_bringup/pr2.launch* so the command for ros-hydro should be

```
 roslaunch pr2_bringup pr2.launch
```

but it's not working. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81636/hydro-pr2-gazebo/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 simulator is not yet supported on Hydro, and has not been released.

When it is released, that proper startup command will be:

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2013-09-20**:
thank you, then i'll go back to groovy meanwhile

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2013-11-04**:
Has this been already released? I could not find any debian package sounding like pr2_gazebo. If this is still up for release: Any guesstimated time for release? Is it possible to checkout the current devel branch of pr2_gazebo and give it a try?

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2013-11-21**:
I tried last week, it's not released yet. I have no idea when it's going to be released. But it's already a long time since hydro came out.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2013-11-25**:
Basically, it seems there are quite some changes needed to have this running in Hydro. However, I have a feeling it will happen at some point in the future. See here for a discussion:
http://lists.willowgarage.com/pipermail/pr2-users/2013-November/001830.html

**Comment by [Maestre](https://answers.ros.org/users/13871/maestre/) on 2014-03-26**:
Dear all, do you have any news about the update of the PR2 simulator to be compatible with Hydro? I just write here not to open a new thread just for this question.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-03-26**:
With pr2_simulator from github (branch hydro-devel), it works ok for me (on some machines). Btw, when there will be indigo branch? ;)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-26**:
I have no estimate on when there will be a release; there are still a number of unresolved issues in the hydro-devel branch. Since there are minimal changes between hydro and indigo, I expect that the hydro-devel branch will work on indigo.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-06-29**:
Now I found it can work on hydro~